# Inserting same value at multiple indices of a List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to insert the same value at multiple indices in an empty list. 
For ex.

```
b=[1,3]
a=[0,0,0,0]
a[b]=10
```

I want to insert the value 10 at index 1 and 3 of a to get a=[0,10,0,10]. What is the simplest way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, just a regular for loop:

```py
b=[1,3]
a=[0,0,0,0]

for i in b:
    a[i]=10

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[0, 10, 0, 10]
```

but, if you use `numpy`, then you can in 1-line with advanced assignment:

```py
import numpy as np

b = [1, 3]
a = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])

a[b] = 10

print(a)
```

Comment: note: I am NOT suggesting to use numpy just for this.

Comment: Thanks for the help.